# What is the difference between keyStorePassword and keyManagerPassword in Jetty?

Tags: java, ssl, jetty, keystore

I am looking at SSL for Jetty: http://wiki.eclipse.org/Jetty/Reference/SSL_Connectors

There are properties for both keyStorePassword and keyManagerPassword.
I suppose the keyManagerPassword is used by a Javax KeyManager, and so
is a password for recovering keys from the key store?

So do keyStorePassword and keyManagerPassword then generally have the same value?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Keymanagerfactory does have a password.

hmmm it is a little history and evolution in these APIs and they could perhaps be made clearer.

The keyManagerPassword is passed as the password arg to KeyManagerFactory.init(...)
If there is no keymanagerpassword, then the keystorepassword is used instead.
If there is no trustmanager set, then the keystore is used as the trust store and the keystorepassword is used as the truststore password.

Comment: The password used by KMF.init should be the same as the `keyPassword` in a number of other tools (and in previous versions of Jetty): that's the one that unlocks the keys themselves (as opposed to the keystore, when they differ and/or are required). I guess a bit of clarification in the documentation would help indeed.

Comment: Thanks all for all the comments! I have some better clarity for my own work now.

Answer (score 1):

`keyManagerPassword` looks like a misfeature. It is the keystore that has the password, not the KeyManager. There's no reference to a key manager password in the Javadoc for the classes concerned.

Comment: also it seems to be some confusion between keyStore and trustManager in the method signatures, I'll open a bug on it to get it cleared up - https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=381351