# Jetty SSL Passwords

Tags: java, ssl, https, jetty

I don't fully understand the passwords that need to be set in the jetty-ssl.xml file for enabling the SSL. I created a self-signed certificate using the keytool, and during the process I had to enter two passwords only, namely *keypass* and *storepass*, which IMO correspond with *KeyStorePassword* and *TrustStorePassword* respectively. That said, this leaves one password left *KeyManagerPassword* which is not yet clear to me where should it have been set during the process.

```
<Configure id="sslContextFactory" class="org.eclipse.jetty.util.ssl.SslContextFactory">
    <Set name="KeyStorePath">
        <Property name="jetty.base" default="." />/
        <Property name="jetty.keystore" default="etc/keystore" />
    </Set>
    <Set name="KeyStorePassword">
        <Property name="jetty.keystore.password" default="OBF:1vny1zlo1x8e1vnw1vn61x8g1zlu1vn4" />
    </Set>
    <Set name="KeyManagerPassword">
        <Property name="jetty.keymanager.password" default="OBF:1u2u1wml1z7s1z7a1wnl1u2g" />
    </Set>
    <Set name="TrustStorePath">
        <Property name="jetty.base" default="." />/
        <Property name="jetty.truststore" default="etc/keystore" />
    </Set>
    <Set name="TrustStorePassword">
        <Property name="jetty.truststore.password" default="OBF:1vny1zlo1x8e1vnw1vn61x8g1zlu1vn4" />
    </Set>
</Configure>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This has been discussed somewhat [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10847983/what-is-the-difference-between-keystorepassword-and-keymanagerpassword-in-jetty). There will not always be a KeyManagerPassword - it is only used if there is one [specified in the key store](http://download.eclipse.org/jetty/stable-9/apidocs/org/eclipse/jetty/util/ssl/SslContextFactory.html#setKeyManagerPassword-java.lang.String-). In most instances the password is the same as the KeyStorePassword. If the value KeyManagerPassword is blank it will default to [the value of KeyStorePassword.](https://github.com/eclipse/jetty.project/blob/jetty-9.3.x/jetty-util/src/main/java/org/eclipse/jetty/util/ssl/SslContextFactory.java#L1067) So in your case you can leave it blank since you did not otherwise set it.